# Which one is better to pass to StringBuilder.append?

Tags: java, string

Out of the two methods in StringBuilder's append, which of the following code is better?

```
stringBuilder.append('\n');
```

or

```
stringBuilder.append("\n");
```

Comment: Better in what way? They are equivalent, the first may have slightly less overhead, but that is likely a trivial difference.

Comment: If you pass a string into `append` then some bit of code somewhere will have to iterate through the string and add every character in it. But there is unlikely to be a measurable performance difference.

Comment: I prefer to use System.lineSeperator ().

Comment: In the first case you're appending a `char` to the `StringBuilder`. In the second case you're using `String` to append. This is really trivial question, I'd consider the @GeorgeZougianos comment.

Comment: You should really use `System.lineSeparator()`. If `\n` is the wrong on your system (like on Windows) then the code won't work as expected and that's not worth the **picosecond** you get with the faster version.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Appending a single `char` (`stringBuilder.append('\n')`) requires less work than appending a `String` (such as `"\n"`), even if the `String` contains only a single character.

Compare `append(char c)`, which basically performs a single assignment to the `value` array:

```
public AbstractStringBuilder append(char c) {
    ensureCapacityInternal(count + 1);
    value[count++] = c;
    return this;
}
```

To `append(String str)`, which requires additional 2 method calls (`str.getChars()` and `System.arraycopy`):

```
public AbstractStringBuilder append(String str) {
    if (str == null)
        return appendNull();
    int len = str.length();
    ensureCapacityInternal(count + len);
    str.getChars(0, len, value, count);
    count += len;
    return this;
}
```

which calls

```
public void getChars(int srcBegin, int srcEnd, char dst[], int dstBegin) {
    if (srcBegin < 0) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(srcBegin);
    }
    if (srcEnd > value.length) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(srcEnd);
    }
    if (srcBegin > srcEnd) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(srcEnd - srcBegin);
    }
    System.arraycopy(value, srcBegin, dst, dstBegin, srcEnd - srcBegin);
}
```

Therefore, in terms of performance, `stringBuilder.append('\n')` is better than `stringBuilder.append("\n")`.

That said, in the specific case of `\n`, you might want to use a third option - `stringBuilder.append(System.lineSeperator ())` . While this has the downside of appending a `String` (which is slower than appending a `char`), it accounts for the fact that different platforms (for example Linux vs. Windows) use different line separators, which sometimes even consist of more than one character. Hence `stringBuilder.append(System.lineSeperator ())` can be considered more correct.

Comment: why faster than me why? +1

Comment: yea today I also want to know why ?

Comment: That's definitely faster in terms of performance, but I would love to know this from coding practices as well.

Comment: Agree with the performance aspect, disagree with `System.lineSeparator()` being more correct. It simply depends on the use case.

Comment: @xehpuk well, if your Java application only targets a single OS, you are probably safe with using the explicit end-of-line character[s] for that OS.

Comment: That's not what I meant. When you're writing to a file, sure, you should use the system-dependent line separator. But when you're e.g. writing to a `JTextPane`, you should always use `\n`.